# google pub sub fetches messages in different times

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a java client of google-pubsub api.

I sent 4 messages at the same time to the pubsub.

My subscriber is triggered once an hour and loop on the pubsub till it's empty.

Nevertheless I see the messages are fetched in different times even though they were all sent at the same time and there was a long delay till the next automated subscriber synchronised fetch.

```java
// A hotfix as cofman is too slow for ack
while (pubSubIsFull) {
    // Fetch messages by order
    log("before fetched messages by order");
    List<ReceivedMessage> messages = mySyncSubscriber.fetch(100000, true);

    messages = messages.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(message2 -> message2.getMessage().getPublishTime().getSeconds())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    log("fetched " + messages.size() + " messages by order");
    pubSubIsFull = messages.size() > 0;

    log("before processMessages");
    List<String> ackIds = processMessages(messages);
    log("after processMessages");
    mySyncSubscriber.sendAck(ackIds);
}
```

```java
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PullRequest.Builder;

public List<ReceivedMessage> fetch(int maxMessages, boolean returnImmediately) {
    String subscriptionName = this.getSubscriptionName(this.getSubscriptionId()).toString();
    Builder pullRequestBuilder = PullRequest.newBuilder().setSubscription(subscriptionName).setReturnImmediately(returnImmediately);

    if (maxMessages != 0) {
      pullRequestBuilder.setMaxMessages(maxMessages);
    }

    PullRequest pullRequest = pullRequestBuilder.build();
    PullResponse pullResponse = (PullResponse)this.subscriber.pullCallable().call(pullRequest);

    return pullResponse.getReceivedMessagesList();
}
```

Is this a bug in pub sub?

Is there something I can do to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub offers no ordering guarantees. If you publish multiple messages--even some time apart--and then later fetch all of the messages, there are no guarantees that the messages published earlier will be received by the subscriber first.

Additionally, receiving 0 messages in a single response is not a good way to determine that no messages are available. Sometimes responses will contain 0 messages even when there are messages available, particularly if `returnImmediately` is set to true (as noted in [my response to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50253241/1121288)). At the very least, you'd want to make sure that several requests over a period of time all return 0 messages before deciding that there are no message available. Even better would be to query the [Stackdriver metric for `subscription/num_undelivered_messages`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub), which indicates the number of messages not yet acknowledged by your subscription.

Comment: many insights with your response! Thank you.

Follow-up to the answer, because I seem to have similar requirements as Elad: If I want to regularily query for new messages (e.g. every 10s) and then process up to a certain maximum (e.g. 100 messages) in order to perform a batch update in a slower system (DB), what is the recommended approach? Doing a synchronous pull seems until we have processed all undelivered messages as indicated by a Stackdriver metric seems to be quite a lot. Is there a recommended way?

Comment: Some background: On AWS I had a good setup with Kinesis/DynamoDB, so I am asking for how to do something similar with PubSub. In the AWS setup, all events are pushed into a Kinesis stream. A Lambda with a batch size of 100 processes the stream, normalizes the events, and saves them with one put to DynamoDB. 

Similar setup with CloudWatch instead of DynamoDB here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-a-time-series-in-real-time-with-aws-lambda-amazon-kinesis-and-amazon-dynamodb-streams/

How should I do this kind of normalization with a PubSub subscriber?